# Conjugate function of the sum of r smallest elements

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I recently came across this problem to find the conjugate function of the sum of $r$ smallest elements in a vector

$f(x) = \sum_{i=n-r+1}^{n}x_{[i]}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$

where $x_{[i]}$ is the $i^{th}$ largest element in vector $x$.

My first approach is as follows:

We consider the following function in two cases:
$$
y^Tx - f(x)
$$
If $y$ has component $y_i \ge 1$ for some $i$, we can construct $x$ such that $x_i$ is very positive ($x_i = t$ where $t >> 0$), and other components of $x$ are all zeros, then
$$
y^Tx - f(x) = y_it \rightarrow \infty
$$
If $y$ has component $y_i < 1$ for some $i$, we can construct $x$ such that $x_i$ is very negative ($x_i = -t$ where $t >> 0$), and other components of $x$ are all zeros, then
$$
y^Tx - f(x) = -y_it + t = (1 - y_i)t \rightarrow \infty
$$Therefore,
$$
f^*(y) = \infty
$$
I wonder if this is the right solution. Any idea is highly appreciated.
Thank you all!